# How Can I scrape data using pagination into an excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint
import pandas as pd

page = requests.get('https://www.arabam.com/ikinci-el/motosiklet/honda?view=List&take=50')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
rows = []
kolon = []
for tr in soup.select('tr'):
    row = [td.text.strip() for td in tr.select('td') if td.text.strip() and td.text.strip() != '-']
    if len(row)>6:
        row[7] = row[7][:-98]
        rows.append(row)
   
  
for column in rows[1:]:
    kolon.append(column)



from openpyxl import load_workbook
writer =pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
wb  = writer.book
df = pd.DataFrame(kolon)
  df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
  wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

We scraped 51 rows of motorcycle information with the code above from first page into test.xlsx but we have to get the data in next pages and we dont know how to add this data onto current test.xlsx file. How can we add diffrent page's datas to previous datas?

Web-site:https://www.arabam.com/ikinci-el/motosiklet/honda?view=List&take=50

[First Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IssM3.png) We scraped those datas
[Second Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzPqA.png) The page that we want to scrape
There is 51 row each page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the number of pages first and then just loop over them to fetch your tables.

Here's how:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

start = 1
response = requests.get(f"https://www.arabam.com/ikinci-el/motosiklet/honda?view=List&take=50&page={start}").text
pagination = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser").select(".pagination > li")

out = []
for page_number in range(start, len(pagination)):
    url = f"https://www.arabam.com/ikinci-el/motosiklet/honda?view=List&take=50&page={page_number}"
    response = requests.get(url).text
    table = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser").find("table", {"id": "main-listing"})
    df = pd.concat(pd.read_html(str(table), header=0)).drop("Unnamed: 0", axis=1)
    out.append(df)

df = pd.concat(out, ignore_index=True)
df.to_csv("all_tables.csv", index=False)
```

This gets you one file with all the table data from each page.